# Internet Connectivity Check

Tags: networking

Hi all and thanks in advance for your help.

I have a situation where I have a need to test an unstable Internet connection on one internal network and send out an email alert on any issues (obviously requiring an Internet connection) through another network - .

I have hardware with dual nic and plan on writing something simple in vb.

Is there a way I can disable ping on my 'good' connection forcing it through the test network yet allowing smtp?

I've looked into routing and done some basic testing but it seems the ping automatically reroutes through the good network shortly after the bad network fails?

Any advice warmly received.

Answer (score 0):

You should not even think about blocking ICMP.  This is a good way to cause many, many problems.  Instead, you should explicitly specify which interface to use for the ping requests.

If you're using a command-line ping, you usually do this by specifying the source IP to use for sending the packets.  For example, on OS X, you can run the command

```
ping -c 5 -S 10.0.1.13 8.8.8.8
```

to ping Google's public DNS server (8.8.8.8) using the interface whose IP address is 10.0.1.13.  If the interface with that IP is down, the ping will fail.

The specific flag varies from implementation to implementation.

If you're writing your own ping code, IIRC, you just need to bind the socket to that source address with the `bind()` system call.